# What does the statement "The cyclic subgroup of $Z_{24}$ generated by $18$ has order $4$" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The group $Z_{24}$ has 24 elements. But $18$ can't generate all those elements. The best it can do is

$18+18=12$

$18+18+18=6$

$18+18+18+18=0$

$18+18+18+18+18=18$

$18+18+18+18+18+18=12$

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have, correctly, proved that $\langle 18\rangle = \{0,6,12,18\}$, a group of order $4$.

Comment: It is a subgroup, therefore the elements will be a subset, not the entire group. I really don't get your confusion, what you did is good.

Comment: Yes 18 can not generate all $Z_{24}$ because $gcd(24,18) \neq 1$

Comment: Ah! I was thinking, $18$ was supposed to generate all the elements in $Z_{24}$. But yes this makes sense. I think I was just getting tripped up by the wording

Answer (score 2):

"The cyclic subgroups of $Z_{24}$ generated by $18$" is the set $\langle 18\rangle =\{18\cdot n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ (this is a subgroup of $Z_{24}$ as I am sure you will have proved in the past). You have shown that this subgroup is equal to $\{0,6,12,18\}$ and hence is a subgroup of order $4$ as required in the title of the question.